# PMTA wont start

Tags: linux, email, centos6

I ran a debug and this is what it spit out...

```
Startup error: Error initializing thread: Error binding socket to 0.0.0.0:25, status = EADDRINUSE
```

Never seen this before. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
Startup error: Error initializing thread: Error binding socket to 0.0.0.0:25, status = EADDRINUSE
```

That means some other process is bound to `0.0.0.0:25`.

Run this to sort out what that process is:

```
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 25
```